# Unable to Select From Dropdown By Index in Selenium and Java

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu

I understand how to Select an element from dropdown using selectByIndex method. Howeverwhen I try to perform selectByIndex ( `select.selectByIndex (index)` ) on the following HTML snippet:

```
<select id="destinationAllocationId" name="destinationAllocationId">
<optgroup label="Anywhere Virtual Cards">
<option value="1555555555f0a19">NNN0 [*-2453]</option>
<option value="1555555555f0519">NNN1 [*-8354]</option>
<option value="155555555550419">NNN2 [*-5765]</option>
<option value="155555555520919">NNN3 [*-8875]</option>
</optgroup>
</select>
</div>
```

I'm unable to maintain the selected option.

At first it appears to work (the dropdown menu opens and the correct option is highlighted inblue). However as soon as the program continues with execution (something unrelated to dropdown) the dro pdown reverts back to the original state (the default option).

In other words, initially the the program selects the appropriate option just fine but it automatically reverts back to the default option and doesn't actually change the value in the dropdown once the dropdown menu disappears (Usually when I select an option manually I can see that option being selected once the drop down is closed however in this case as long as dropdown is open the option is selected but as soon as it closes the default option is selected)

Any ideas why this happens

Comment: Are you possibly setting some other value on the page that is resetting this dropdown? e.g., some dropdowns fill/reset others. Can you post more of the code around setting the option. Seems like something strange is going on. I use Java/Selenium and I don't remember ever seeing a dropdown open... the value usually just gets set without opening the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

i had this issue, too

this is how i solved it

```
/**
 * helper method for handling drop downs
 * @param idPrefix the id of the drop down without any _xy
 * @param value the value to be selected
 */
public void clickDropdown(String idPrefix, String value) {
    // find & click on the label element of the drop down
    firefoxDriver.findElement(By.id(idPrefix + "_label")).click();
    // find & choose element from drop down
    firefoxDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='" + idPrefix + "_panel']/div/ul/li[text()='" + value + "']")).click();
}
```

u call it like this:

```
// choosing an element in the drop down menu
clickDropdown("projectForm:stellvertreter", "StringToSelect");
```

this i wrote for use with primefaces, you have to modify it anyway but u get the idea

for the issue with selecting and reverting... try sending an enter key press to the selected item or clicking it again... didnt have that with my approach